# Cambiar el propietario de un area de trabajo en Team Foundation

Tags: visual-studio

Buenas tardes a todos,

Tengo un proyecto en VS2012 conectado a un TFS. Descargué el proyecto en mi local con un usuario que ha sido dado de baja y el área de trabajo asociada a ese usuario y proyecto está definida como privada (no me dí cuenta de cambiarla).

Ahora ya tengo otro usuario para conectarme al TFS, pero al ser el área de trabajo privada no me deja cambiar/eliminar la asignación de la carpeta local del proyecto ni el propietario de ese área, puesto que pertenecen al usuario eliminado.

Es necesario que la solución aportada no implique la eliminación de los fuentes ni reinstalación de VS, puesto que no es algo viable.

Dicho esto, mis preguntas son:

- ¿Hay algún fichero de configuración dentro del equipo que indique quien es el propietario del área de trabajo y que yo pueda editar?
- Si no es posible esto, ¿hay algún comando para hacerlo desde mi equipo local?

He estado investigando por Internet y todas las soluciones que he encontrado requieren que el usuario anterior exista.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nivel corporativo (en la que los usuarios no son administradores ni tienen disponibilidad de instalar software) hay otra solución, que debe ser ejecutada por un administrador de Team Foundation, y es ejecutar uno de los siguientes comandos:

Para cambiar el propietario del área de trabajo:

```
tf workspaces /updateUserName:OLD_USER /s:http://SERVER /login:NEW_USER
```

Para eliminar el área de trabajo:

```
tf workspace /delete WORKSPACE;OLD_USER /server:http://SERVER /login:NEW_USER
```

Si el nuevo usuario (usuario que se indica en `/login`) no tiene permisos para lanzarlo devolverá este error:

> TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to
> complete the operation: *NEW_USER*. The following permissions are
> needed to perform this operation: View collection-level information.

Para ejecutar estos comandos sería desde el la consola de TFS en el servidor o desde la consola de VS en un pc. La consola de VS es esta, dentro de la carpeta de instalación de Visual Studio 2012 (en mi caso):

[image: Herramientas nativas VS2012]

Espero que os sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

> Es necesario que la solución aportada no implique la eliminación de los fuentes ni reinstalación de VS, puesto que no es algo viable.

Es posible utilizando el programa [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta @Carlos ¿Hay alguna solución portable de este programa? No soy administrador del equipo local y no puedo instalar software...

Comment: Lo siento, no que yo sepa :(

Comment: He conseguido que me instalen el sw y un detalle importante es que el usuario debe tener autorización para leer el registro.

Comment: Aunque tu respuesta es útil (y por eso la he votado como tal) no me soluciona puesto que en un entorno corporativo los usuarios no suelen tener permisos de administrador en sus equipos, por lo que no pueden leer el registro y el programa que propones no se puede ejecutar. De todas formas, muchas gracias por responder.